# input not submitting data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm making a very simple groups(like vb forum groups). I've coded all of it, after getting some errors and fixing it now it's showing the page without errors.

The problem now is the data ISN'T being inserted to mysql. When putting the input into forms and then pressing create it goes to "?update=update" and echo's the success message, but doesn't submit to mysql.

Code:

```
<? if(!$update) { ?>
<form action="make_group.php?update=update" method="post">

Group name: <br />
<input name="title" type="text" size="30" />
<br />

Group picture: <br />
<input name="picture" type="text" size="30" />
<br />

Group desc: <br />
<textarea name="desc" cols=30 rows=10 wrap=physical></textarea>
<br />

        <input type="submit" value="Create" />


    <? }

    elseif($update==update)
    {
        $username = $_SESSION[usr_name];
        $action = "made a group";
    $title = clean($_POST[title]);
    $desc = clean($_POST[desc]);
    $pictures = clean($_POST[pictures]);
        $updateemail = mysql_query("insert into usr_groups(username, title, desc, picture) values('$username', '$title', '$desc', '$picture')");
        $result = @mysql_query($qry2);
    echo("Your group has been created");
    } ?>
```

Above page code

```
<?
session_start();
include("config.php");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sqlcontent = mysql_query("select * from usr_config");
$content = mysql_fetch_array($sqlcontent);

if(!isset($_SESSION[usr_name]) || empty($_SESSION[usr_name]) || !isset($_SESSION[usr_level]) || empty($_SESSION[usr_level]))
{
session_destroy();
session_unset();
die('
    <tr>
      <td><meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=/index.php"></HEAD></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>');
}
include("func.php");

$update = clean($_GET[update]);
$getprof = mysql_query("select * from usr_users where username = '$_SESSION[usr_name]'");
$prof = mysql_fetch_array($getprof);
?>
```

Comment: `elseif($update==update)`
should be elseif($update=='update')
and there are quotes missing in many places.

Comment: That's not the problem. I'm using the same code as account settings(which works perfectly) but slightly changed to insert, instead of updating.

Comment: try to echo `$updateemail` and then add this code to check if there are any errors.
`if (!mysql_query($updateemail,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";`

Comment: Checked for errors: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, picture) values('admin', 'wffqw3', 'rwg', '')' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Set off the desc with ` - amending my answer to include my comment from below - desc is a reserved word in MySQL, to declare it as a field name instead of a sort order, it must have the back ticks:)

I would suggest putting adding an OR die(mysql_error()) to the end of your mysql_query(call)

```
    mysql_query('your query') OR die(mysql_error())
```

I would only do this while your debugging and not leave it on anything the public would see.  This will give you information on why the INSERT query isn't working.  I don't where you are connecting, but I'm assuming you left that out for security reasons :)

I do see that your statement

```
    elseif($update==update){
```

doesn't have quotes around it - so it would seem like that conditional block is never being called...I see your comment, but I would consider at least for debugging purposes, throwing some quotes around it.  Can't hurt right :) the die statement will tell you if you have syntax issues.  Maybe consider printing something in that block as well to make sure that conditional is interpreted the way you are expecting...

FWIW your SQL appear to be fine to me - you may run into issues with the name if you ever get a ' in the name...

Comment: Is your clean function escaping quotes?  If not, that will have unintended consequences if someone provides a description with an apostrophe in it...

Comment: Checked for errors: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, picture) values('admin', 'wffqw3', 'rwg', '')' at line 1

Comment: desc is the mysql abbreviation for descending sort order, you'll need to set it off in back ticks ` desc ` (don't include the spaces...I just added them to avoid the auto formatting) to tell the query you aren't referring to the MySQL desc keyword

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo `$updateemail` and then add this code to check if there are any errors.

```
if (!mysql_query($updateemail,$con)) { 
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

echo "1 record added";

Also,change the insert query to :

```
$updateemail = mysql_query("insert into usr_groups(username, title, description, picture) values('$username', '$title', '$desc', '$pictures')");
```

change the desc column name to something.

Comment: Could you please echo the query? 
also please check if the table column fields `data types` are defined correctly.Also, do you have a user defined `clean` function ?

Comment: Oops , the insert query is to be changed I suppose.
Its `$pictures` and not `$picture`.

Comment: Why isn't it working when it's nearly the same as my account settings? The only different is it's inserting, not updating? This is so weird!

Comment: change the `desc` column name to something.

Answer (score 0):

change $picture to $pictures

```
$updateemail = mysql_query("insert into usr_groups(username, title, desc, picture) values('$username', '$title', '$desc', '$pictures')");
```

Unable to insert if column named is keyword, such as DESC

Comment: That was a mistake. It was actually picture. I've already changed them all to picture... still not instering though!

Comment: change the name of 'desc' column to description

Comment: Changing the name of the field would be a good idea, although it's not required...putting back ticks around the field name will prevent the error as well